# AWK If/ElseConditional Problem

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk

I have a data that looks like this:

```
foo foo      scaffold_7      1 4845 6422 4845
bar bar      scaffold_7      -1 14689 16310 16310
```

What I want to do is to process the above lines
where I just want to print column 1,2,3, 7 and one more column after 7th.
But with condition when printing column 7 onwards.

Below is my awk script:

```
awk '{ 
        if ($4=="+") { {end=$6-$5}{print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $4 "\t" $7 "\t" end+$7} } 
        else 
            {end=$6-$5}{print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $4 "\t" $7-end "\t" $7} 
    }'
```

But why it doesn't achieve the desired result like this?

```
foo foo    scaffold_7      1       4845    6422
bar bar   scaffold_7      -1      14689   16310
```

Note that the arithmetic (e.g. `$7-end` or `end+$7`) is a must. So we can't just swap column 
from input file. Furthermore this AWK will be inside a bash script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS = "\t"} { 
    end = $6 - $5
    if ($4 >= 0) {
        print $1, $2, $3, $4, $7, end + $7
    } else {
        print $1, $2, $3, $4, $7 - end, $7
    }
}'
```

I've never used braces within braces and prefer the semi-colon separators for this purpose. I'm pretty certain the else clause is bound *only* to `{end=$6-$5}` in your example, not to both the braced entries. In that case, `{print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $4 "\t" $7-end "\t" $7}` will be executed for *all* lines.

Comment: Neater, shorter, easier to change: `awk -vOFS='\t' '{ ... print $1, $2 ... `

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '{end=$6-$5}
$4>0{ $0=$1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $4 "\t" $7 "\t" end+$7 }
$4<=0{$0=$1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $4 "\t" $7-end "\t" $7 }1'  file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo 'foo foo      scaffold_7      1 4845 6422 4845
bar bar      scaffold_7      -1 14689 16310 16310' | \
awk -v OFS='\t' '{
    print( \
        $1, $2, $3, $4, 
        ( \
            $4>0 ? $7 OFS ($6-$5) + $7 : $7 - ($6-$5) OFS $7 \
        ) \
    )
}'

foo     foo     scaffold_7      1       4845    6422
bar     bar     scaffold_7      -1      14689   16310
```

Answer (score 0):

or condense it to one-liner without repeating the `print` statement  :

```
 jot -s ' ' 7 -532 098 | mawk '{ print; $4=-$4; print }' |
```

> ```
> mawk '($5 =(__ = $6 - $5) * -!(_ = -(_ = +$4)<_) + \
>       ($6 = $7) )^(OFS = "\t") + ($--NF += _*__)'
> ```

```
-532    -427    -322    -217    -112     -7    98
-532    -427    -322    -217      -7     98

-532    -427    -322     217    -112     -7    98
-532    -427    -322     217      98    203
```